# Why need projectname.exe.config to run exe file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have developed a vb.net application using visual studio 2010 and MS SQL Server 2014. I have used crystal reports for reporting purpose.

target framwork 4.0

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
```

using crystal reports as 
Build Action = Embedded Resource
Copy to output directory = Do not copy

in code crystal report is accessed as

Dim cryRpt As New myReportName
cryRpt.SetDataSource(xdataset.Tables(0))

problem is when I run myproject.exe located in myProject\bin\Debug, it works fine both for forms and crystal reports.

but if myproject.exe is copied to any other location, it crashes on run, where dataset is assigned to report. 
Now if I copy myproject.exe.config file at same location as of exe file, it runs successfully.

so why exe file needs myproject.exe.config to run if it using dataset for records.
do I need to deploy myproject.exe.config with my exe file too?

regards.

this is code inside my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
        <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="FileLog"/>
                <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="FileLog"
             type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
             initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
        <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Some things rely on configuration, that is just how it is.

Comment: You don't need a config file to run an EXE. If some of the code in your application relies on configuration data stored in the config file though, obviously it's going to be a problem if that config file isn't present. In your case, it may well be that your config file contains the database connection string.

Comment: If you are publishing the app, you can look at properties > publish > application files and set the config file as an included file that is required and it will get included with the distribution.

Comment: config code is added, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`My.Settings` uses the .exe.config file I think. Easiest is to open it and see what settings are stored inside. You can then change your code to store those settings elsewhere.

Comment: This is a vb.net winforms application